# Screen won't turn on during a call

Tags: proximity-sensor

As soon as I'm connected on a call, both outgoing and ingoing, the screen goes blank, even if it's sitting on a desk (i.e. it's not the result of the proximity sensor).

I can't get the screen to go back on until the call is ended.  Pressing the power button does nothing; pressing the power button and then the fingerprint sensor gives the phone a brief vibration, but does nothing for the screen.

I can still speak and hear during the call, I just can't interact with the screen in any way.

Once the call is over, I can get the screen back on via power button + fingerprint sensor.

My Settings has no option under Calls for turning the screen on or off.

(Google Pixel XL, Android 8.1.0)

Comment: I guess it's faulty proximity sensor I had same problem with lg (suprise suprise) where screen goes black or doesn't turn off when it should solution was to recalibrate sensor I can't remember how I did it I think I had to boot into some mini OS or use some dieler code. To see if your sensor work properly download app called Aida 64 and in app under sensors find proximity and hover you sensor (in most cases it's above screen) and see if vaule has changed it mostly return 1 or 0, if not try searching how to recalibrate proximity sensor, if value is changing than problem is in settings or bug

Comment: Also in my case turning it off and on resolved problem temporarily. Keep in mind that in your case it may be a software bug see if there is an update, there should be android 9 available.

Comment: I installed Aida 64.  is TMD4903 Proximity Sensor what I'm looking for?  It's the only "proximity sensor" listed.  Its value never changes from 0.0 cm.

Comment: Well if it's only one labeled with proximity sensor than yes. Well that means that it's either hardware or software failure. Now I can't find any solution on how to recalibrate sensor but I find article for pixel 2 XL in which it says it received fix in June this year. I would contact support to see if there is workaround for recalibration. Did you dropped phone maybe in time when sensor started making troubles?